# Limit results of Mongodb find() query not working

Tags: mongodb

I must be overlooking really simple, here's a sample of my db :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545e7e45a69b6c5c0caeafcc"), "url" : "http://example.com/id=4314936", "name" : "product1", "retailer" : "123", "extra" : [ ], "timestamp" : 1415478797263, "processed" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545e7e45a69b6c5c0caeafcc"), "url" : "http://example.com/id=4314936", "name" : "product2", "retailer" : "123", "extra" : [ ], "timestamp" : 1415478797263, "processed" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545e7e45a69b6c5c0caeafcc"), "url" : "http://example.com/id=4314936", "name" : "product3", "retailer" : "123", "extra" : [ ], "timestamp" : 1415478797263, "processed" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("545e7e45a69b6c5c0caeafcc"), "url" : "http://example.com/id=4314936", "name" : "product3", "retailer" : "123", "extra" : [ ], "timestamp" : 1415478797263, "processed" : 0 }
```

I'm trying to get 2 results only using :

```
db.products.find({timestamp:1415478797263,processed:0},{},{limit:2})
```

I have read and tried similar questions on Stack Overflow, so please keep that in mind before flagging as duplicate.

No matter what I try it gives me the full set... The strangest thing is that I'm using a similar find() elsewhere and it works. An experienced pair of eyes should be able to spot the problem, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query, does it work?

```
 db.products.find({timestamp:1415478797263,processed:0}).limit(2)
```

now to use it with node js native driver you can do this

```
      db.products.find({timestamp:1415478797263,processed:0}).limit(2).each(function(err, doc) {

         console.dir(doc);
    });
```

or in array form you can get this as

```
    db.products.find({timestamp:1415478797263,processed:0}).limit(2).toArray(function(err, docs)          {            
      console.log("Returned #" + docs.length + " documents");
    })
```

Comment: yes, it works! Now I gotta find out how to translate that in node native driver.

Comment: well, I was actually reading the api doc to see if I could use .limit(), but thanks for editing!

Comment: and now you're reading my mind, I was checking about toArray :) Thanks man, I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer lets me

Comment: thanks , was just expecting that you will need it too :)

Comment: Oddly when I use the mongo command.. and use limit(0) - which reads as no limits - it doesn't work - you still get the Type "it" for more message.